# Changing a hashgacha stamp after the rav's death

Tags: hechsher-certification

I've noticed recently that wines which we get under the hashgacha of the Bada"tz Beit Yosef list "R' Ovadia Yosef **Shlit"a**." As R' Ovadia died more than a year ago and these are young wines, I suspect that they were bottled and stamped with his hechsher after his death.

Considering this, is it improper to maintain a hashgacha stamp which lists a rav who is deceased with the honorific of "*shlit"a*"?

Comment: What do you mean by "improper"?

Comment: "adjective
not in accordance with accepted rules or standards"

Comment: Is the problem specifically about the use of "Shlita"? I don't see that, in itself, as a kashrut problem. The main question is that it seems misleading to use a hashgacha stamp of someone who isn't even alive! Old items that are still on the shelf, of course, can't be changed. Problem is, when you buy a product, is there a clear method of knowing if you're getting an old or a new item? Is this the type of product where people would tend to check the expiration date?

Comment: @DanF, I suspect that it might be some sort of false advertising, as it implies that the R' hamachshir is different from the present one (R' Ploni's successor, as opposed to R' Ploni)

Comment: @NoachmiFrankfurt I would agree. My main question is say someone buys a product that was certified by Rav P who is *niftar*. When viewing the label, how does one know if it's an old label or it's misleading? If the product has a packaging date, that helps. An expiration date probably wouldn't. What works, here?

Answer (score 6):

I do not see why one can not continue using up labels made prior to the Rav's death. This can be a true Hefsed Meruba / large monetary loss. [The symbol has been updated](http://www.naamaspice.com/upload/editor/beit%20yossef%20[640x480].jpg) and I am sure that all new labels are printed with the updated symbol.

Comment: I wasn't aware that it had been updated, although that's likely because the last hashgachot I saw still used shlita

Answer (score 1):

In America anyway, hechshers are trademarks. Changing it to z"l would be a different trademark. When a thing has a hecsher it should be understood that the body that owns the tm rights and not R ovadia is doing it. When moshiach comes will all books authored by the arizal need to be recalled and relabeled?

Comment: Considering that the Arizal didn't write any books, no.